# How to configure and use tracker hierarchies?

Tags: tuleap

Using Tuleap  8.13.99.12 on Centos 6.7

I am trying to set up a hierarchy so that artifacts in one tracker are the children of artifacts in the parent tracker.

I have two trackers called 'Projects' and 'Tasks'.

'Projects' just holds project name and contact details.

'Tasks' uses the tasks template and I want to link each new task to a parent 'Projects' artifact.

In tracker admin I have made 'Tasks' the child of 'Projects'.

However, when I create a new task there is no option to select its parent artifact.

I tried adding an artifact link and that will let me link 'Tasks' to 'Projects' but when I go back to the 'Projects' tracker there are no entries showing up under the Children tab so I guess that's not the right way to do it.

It seems I can't work out how to use tracker hierarchies at all.

Are there any simple instructions on setting up and using tracker hierarchies?
Or is there an example somewhere I can look at so I can see how it should be done or where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I added an Artifact Link field to both trackers.

Then I set up the hierarchy between the two trackers from the administration section of the tracker that I wanted to be the parent.

Once that was done every time I added a child artifact it appeared in the children list of the parent which is what I wanted.